# How do I make Asynchronous calls in WCF with shared contract assemblies?

Tags: wcf

It is easy to do Asynchronous calls if the client proxy is created with “add service reference”, just call the `BeginMyMethod()` and `EndMyMethod()` calls on the generated client interface.

However what you I do when I am used an interface that is defined in shared contract assemblies?

E.g. the interface only contains `MyMethod()`

---

Is there a way to do this without editing the interface, .e.g.

```
CallAsyn("MyMethod", input1, input2)
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808598/why-do-i-get-invalidcastexception-from-operationcontext-current-getcallbackchanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the BeginMyMethod and EndMyMethod methods yourself. Check [this link](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/26/async-operations-in-wcf-iasyncresult-model-server-side/) for more info.

Comment: I have defined my own interface that have the Begin/End methods added, however when I call OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyInterface> I get told that the proxy can not be cassed to IMyInterface