# Why do I get InvalidCastException from OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<>()

Tags: .net, wcf

So as to enable aysc callbacks to the clients, I need to add the Begin/End methods to the interface that is defined as the CallbackContract on my service.  *(I am using a sheared contract assembly, rather than generating proxy classes)*

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IClient)]
interface IEngineManager
```

As the first step I have **just copied** the IClient interface from the shared interface assembly into a local name space, without making any other changes.   I would expect that as the interface is **logically** the same as what is in the contract, WCF will allow it to be used.  **However WCF does not like it for some reason, why?**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IClient
{
  [OperationContract(Action = "ReceiveMessage", 
     ReplyAction = "ReceiveMessageResponse")]
  void ReceiveMessage(SimMessage message);
}

//....
// this give the InvalidCastException
var client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<MyNameSpace.IClient>();
```

However if I just use the original IClient interface from the shared contract assembly, it all works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DxCK siad the type that is passed to OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel`<T`>() must be exactly the same type as you specified in the [ServiceContract] attribute on the interface that the service implements.

However I need to use a different interface for the callbacks so I can add the Begin/End methods needed to support aysc callbacks.

So firstly my new callback interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IClientWithAsyncMethods : IClient
{
  [OperationContract(
    AsyncPattern = true, 
    Action = "ReceiveMessage", 
    ReplyAction = "ReceiveMessageResponse")]
  IAsyncResult BeginReceiveMessage(SimMessage message, 
    AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

  void EndReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}
```

Then need to define a new interface for my service to implment:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientWithAsyncMethods))]
public interface IEngineManagerWithAsyncCallbacks : IEngineManager
{
}
```

The only change to to refare to the new callback interface as the CallbackContract, this is OK as IClientWithAsyncMethods is a subtype of IClient.

Then  the last step is to change the serve implementation to use to the service interface:

- Change the interface type the service implements
- Pass the new interface into ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint() (and/or edit the WCF config files)
- Use IClientWithAsyncMethods in the call to OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel`<IClientWithAsyncMethods`>()

The rest is just calling the aysc method in the normal way.

Answer (score 2):

When you do GetCallbackChannel you should specify exactly the same type as you specfied in the [ServiceContract] attribute, its strongly typed.

Even if A.IClient and B.IClient have exactly the same code with only namespace changed, those are completely different types from .NET's view.